# Running Transmission depending on which wi-fi you are connected to

Tags: wireless, transmission

I wish to set up Transmission so that it always runs on my home wi-fi network, but does not when I'm connected to any other networks.

Is there a way to set things up so that this is the case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a script, call it `check_transmission`, save it in `~/bin/check_transmission`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set your HOME_ESSID here, make note of single and double quotes
HOME_ESSID='ESSID:"your_wireless_home_network_name"'

# Get your current MY_ESSID (network name)
MY_ESSID=$(iwconfig | awk '/ESSID {print $4}')

# Test if you are on your home network and if so
# Start Transmission
[ ${MY_ESSID} == ${HOME_ESSID} ] && transmission &
```

Make it executable

```
chmod u+x ~/check_transmission
```

Run `gnome-session-properties` and add it to your startup programs

(Use the "Add" button , put `/home/your_user/check_transmission` in the dialog)

[image]